# remove unwanted spaces in string in oracle

Tags: oracle

I have a query on SQL in Oracle.

I have a text in one of free-text column of an Oracle table.

The value is:

```
"This is a  test   value"
```

I want to change this to more appropriate which is

```
"This is a test value"`
```

I have used REGEX_REPLACE function however it removed all the spaces. As mentioned I do want the correct space to be displayed in the text but want to remove the unwanted.

Please can anybody help me out in this?

Thanks
Yash

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is how I would approach it:

```
select
  regexp_replace ( 'This is a  test   value', '\s+', ' ')
from dual
```

Bear in mind this will also replace all multiple whitespaces, such as tabs, as well as spaces.  If you really just want spaces:

```
select
  regexp_replace ( 'This is a  test   value', ' +', ' ')
from dual
```